# Using .Net how do I use the Sort method to sort an Array in reverse i.e. Z to A?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

Using .Net how do I use the Sort method to sort an Array in reverse i.e. Z to A?

Answer (score 11):

Provide an appropriate element comparer. What C# version do you use? 3 lets you do this:

```
Array.Sort(myarray, (a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) object or [Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) delegate to the Sort function.

Here is a sample code from C# 2.0

```
   Array.Sort(array,delegate(string a, string b)
    {
        return b.CompareTo(a);
    });
```

EDIT: missed the array bit.

Comment: Why not simply return b.CompareTo(a)?

Comment: There are actually two important differences here:

1) What should happen to null strings? Often when reversing comparisons you *don't* want to reverse what happens to nulls. Just a thought. 2) Returning -a.CompareTo(b) (i.e. pre-edit) causes problems if int.MinValue is returned by a.CompareTo(b).

Comment: I'm pretty sure most string sorting algorithms, like this one, would throw NullReferenceExceptions if there is a null value in the list.  However, the point you bring up in #1 remains for empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a different comparitor that is the reverse of the standard that would do it.

Alternatively sort it normally and then reverse it...